# Regarding Events in Openbravo onSave need to get an client and set it into other class object

Tags: events, data-access-layer, openbravo

Here My code

Need to populate it from a class and then set in to another class especially all columns in product to product detail (Some How i managed other but My Problem is regarding Client. It is not showing anything)

```
public void onSave(@Observes EntityNewEvent event) {
if (!isValidEvent(event)) {
  return;
}
final Entity product_Shift =ModelProvider.getInstance().getEntity(OCAProducts.ENTITY_NAME);
    ProductsDetails pd = OBProvider.getInstance().get(ProductsDetails.class);


final Property pro_client = product_Shift.getProperty(OCAProducts.PROPERTY_CLIENT);

pd.setClient((Client) event.getCurrentState(pro_client));

OBDal.getInstance().save(pd);
OBDal.getInstance().flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

`Getter` and `setter` methods do not work in Openbravo event handlers. Check the document from Openbravo's wiki [**`here`**](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/How_to_implement_a_business_event_handler#Changing_the_entity_on_update.2Finsert).

**An excerpt from the wiki page.**

> don't call setters on the Greeting instance itself, this does not work
>   because when the event has been broadcasted, Hibernate has already
>   read the state of the object. So you must change the value through the
>   special `setCurrentState` method

**Example**

```
 event.setCurrentState(clientProperty, clientId);

 event.setCurrentState(pro_client, clientID)
```